# How would I create a multiple table subquery from a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, terminal

So I know how to create the query using a JOIN but how do I turn this JOIN into a subquery? I have been trying all sorts of things but I just can't figure it out.

My join looks like this:

```
SELECT 
     c.email_address, o.order_id, o.order_date 
FROM 
     customer c 
     JOIN orders o ON (c.customer_id = o.customer_id) 
ORDER BY 
     order_date;
```

My attempt at creating the multiple table:

```
SELECT 
     c.email_address, o.order_id, o.order_date
FROM 
     customer c 
WHERE 
     c.customer_id IN (SELECT o.customer_id FROM orders o) 
ORDER BY 
     o.order_date;
```

I keep getting an error of `unknown column` for both `order_id` and `order_date`

Comment: You can't do that.. `Subquery` are different from `Join` and subquery just return one.. Why do `Join` simple not help you?

Comment: Your second query is not efficient.. Better the first query.. Why do you must do second query getting work? Please provide more info..